# javascript replace matches after regex exec

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, exec

I have this text:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    myText: something1
    othertext
    myText: something2
    othertext
    myText: something3
    ....
<div>
```

I'm matching only the text after the string: `myText:` on multiple lines
using this js:

```
var myDivText = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
var r = /myText:\s*([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/gim;
var m;
while ((m = r.exec(myDivText)) != null){
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

It outputs properly: `something1`, `something2`, `something3`, etc.

Now I need to replace these matches with the word `"ReplacedWord"`

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try `.replace()`?  If so, what did you try and where did you get stuck?  If you didn't try it yet, that's what you should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.replace()` directly on the original string:

```
var myDivText = document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
var temp = myDivText.replace(/(myText:\s*)([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/gim, "$1ReplacedWord")
console.log(temp);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lbhxudv2/

Explanation: I added a new group at the start of the regex to capture the part of the match that you don't want to replace.  Then, the replace string is "$1ReplacedWord" which adds that first match part back into the replacement.

Comment: So is this a sort of javascript lookbehind?

Comment: @user3542686 - It's not technically a lookbehind.  It matches the whole thing and then replaces the whole thing with the first part of the match plus a new part.  This is a common technique.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

If you have already tried this and it did not work, what were your results?

For example, inside your while statement, you can call:

```
myDivText.replace(m[1], "ReplacedWord");
```

or

```
myDivText.replace(m[1], m[1]+"_Replaced");
```

Comment: Yes, `replace()` is the right tool, but you should use it *instead of* `exec()`, not in addition to it.  See [jfriend00's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26415864/20938) for the correct approach.